# how to import the calculated values from cell in laravel / excelinstead of their formulas?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

please give me a simple and good solution for importing the calculated values of cell instead of their formulas while importing?

```php
public function import()
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <=2 ; $i++) {
        $import = new SiteImport();
        $import->onlySheets('SiteImport');
        Excel::import($import, 'C:\Users\ahmad\OneDrive\Desktop\sites\site'.$i.'.xlsx');
    }

    return redirect('/site');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already listed on [Maatwesite excel repo](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1871)

To get the calculated value of a formula just add the below line

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;
```

Comment: `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 50331656 bytes)`

Comment: There must be some error in your code. try increasing your in `php.ini` file `memory_limit = 2048M`

Comment: @Ahmad have you restarted your server after updating php.ini file?

Comment: **Allowed memory size of 790626304 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)**

Comment: Allowed memory size of 790626304 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)